# Print 3 x 3 html table where all 9 cells have same size and completely fill A4 page without margins

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a html page consisting of a table with 3 columns and 3 rows.
When printing this table to an A4 page (portrait) then all 9 cells should have exactly the same height and width and should occupy the complete A4 page without any margins.
Moreover each cell should have a border (1px).

You can use below table to demonstrate the solution.
Note that the actual table cells will be far more complex as they will itself contain images, text with rounded borders, ... but I don't think that this would impact the solution for this question.

```html
<table id="countries">
  <tr>
    <td>Spain</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Belgium</td>
    <td>South Africa</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <br>
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  <br>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco  <br>
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  <br>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit  <br>
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.  <br>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt  <br>
    mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
    <td>Netherlands</td>
    <td>Russia</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this print query.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  table {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  td {
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 33.3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="countries">
  <tr>
    <td>Spain</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Belgium</td>
    <td>South Africa</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <br> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco <br> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      <br> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit <br> esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <br> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt <br> mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
    <td>Netherlands</td>
    <td>Russia</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not all cells have the same width when printing from chrome browser.  I am looking for a solution where all 9 cells have exactly the same width and height.

Comment: All cells have indeed same width but not same height in case one cell contains more lines of text than other cells (for this I have updated example).

Comment: did you try my last edit? because looks like same height and width. see https://i.stack.imgur.com/opvlu.png

Comment: Your last edit is doing the job.  I have accepted this as solution.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED :** You can not achieve that using table maybe. However, you can do it like this using `flex`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html,
.table {
  height: 100%;
}

.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.table,
.cell {
  border: 0.5px solid;
}

.cell {
  height: 33.33%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">Spain</div>
  <div class="cell">Germany</div>
  <div class="cell">Italy</div>
  <div class="cell">Belgium</div>
  <div class="cell">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <br> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco <br> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    <br> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit <br> esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <br> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
  </div>
  <div class="cell">South Africa</div>
  <div class="cell">UK</div>
  <div class="cell">Netherlands</div>
  <div class="cell">Russia</div>
</div>
```

Comment: All cells have indeed same width but not same height in case one cell contains more lines of text than other cells (for this I have updated the example).

Comment: I would like to have all cells having exactly same width and height.

Comment: @JanVdA I am asking that what do you want to happen if the content is more that the limit a cell contain? You want to hide that?

Comment: You can assume that the content fits the cell when printing to A4.

Comment: @JanVdA if the content of the cells, will be fitting inside the cell, then there should be no problem. The difference in the height is negligible.

Comment: it is true in case all cells contain only 1 line of text.  In case one of the cells contains multiple lines (I have updated example - see above) then that row will have a bigger height than the other rows.

Comment: @JanVdA I have updated the code. It is exactly what you wanted, however not using table.